# Facebook Login popup won't close in IE10 on Windows 8

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, internet-explorer-10

The site I am working on uses Facebook Javascript SDK, as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/, to allow users to login. The site is an ASP.NET MVC site.

It works on latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and also IE9.

However in windows 8 consumer preview using IE10 (in normal and compatibility mode) when logging into Facebook the popup window goes white and doesn't close. If close manually and refresh the original page I see that I am logged in.

I have looked through all other SO questions and searched the web. I have tried all the solutions and none of them work.

I am using the channelUrl correctly and it works in the other browsers. I also tried the IE10 bug fix here http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

There really isn't much different from my code and the Facebook examples. So I think there is either a problem with IE10 or the Facebook API when using IE10.

Has anyone had similar problems and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the HTML. The meta tag for http-equiv was set to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8">
```

This causes IE10 to display the web page in IE8 mode. Changed this to 9 as it was meant to be and the Facebook popup box disapears.